# Hive Query - Export to MY computer

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to export a hive query to my local machine in an excel format... for example

```
 hive -S -e "USE DATABASE; select * from TABLE limit 10" > /tmp/hello/test.csv;
```

I have tried nearly everything to export this to MY computer, however, nothing seems to be working. The code above seems to put it in hive local file but I cannot find the actual file on my computer... Can someone please help :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '<Your Local Dir >' ROW FORMAT
 DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' select * from <your table name >;
```

Before running the query, we need to check whether the local directory we are planning to write have all the necessary permissions or not.

Comment: how do i get if from the local directory to my own machine tho?

Comment: you can use winscp if you have ssh connection available to that machine. If you have Hue access, you can run the query using Hive and store the results as csv ( there are other options also ) into your own machine.

Comment: No access to hue unfortunately

Comment: Can you try to use WinScp or Filezilla to copy the results  to your own machine from the local directory ?

Comment: I am ssh'ing into the remote hadoop local file system. I am trying to get the file onto my personal computer.

Comment: that's fine. you can download winscp/filezilla and connect to the remote hadoop local system using the same ssh credentials , then you can copy the files from the remote system to your local computer.

Comment: I downloaded filezilla - no idea how to connect to the hadoop location though.

Comment: You can create a session with the ssh credentials.

Comment: Yeah I did the host by doing ifconfig under the hadoop terminal and used the inet address. the username, is that before or after (sudo su -)?

Comment: the username is the one you use to connect to ssh. ( Not the one you do  sudo to ).

Comment: I did that and connected - but now how do I get to the sudo - su user? - when I click on the sudo - su user it says permission denied

Comment: Ideally if you can connect via ssh, then you could also connect via filezilla.